# Inherited Site Roles not displayed

Tags: permissions, liferay, liferay-6

This was the working scenario earlier:

LDAP Group > LR User Group > LR Role

LDAP Groups were mapped to Liferay User Groups
Liferay User Groups mapped to Liferay Regular Roles
Custom Portlet custom actions/permissions defined on Regular Roles.

When a user logged in from an LDAP group , all the custom actions/permissions assigned to the mapped Regular Role of that specific User Group were working great and the grass was green. **I could see the Inherited Role of that user in the Edit User settings - control panel.**

Now I was working on assigning Site specific roles instead of regular roles.

LDAP Group > LR User Group > Site Role
(Create a Site > Create Site Roles > Map LR User Groups to Site and Site Roles)

But I am not able to see these inherited roles in the Edit User Settings in control panel.
**Will my custom portlet custom actions/permissions be inherited if I define them for Site Roles?**